# get item from stream provider of list

Tags: flutter

I used stream provider to get list of posts from Firestore

```
StreamProvider<List<Post>>.value(value: DatabaseService().posts)
```

I used this to get the list

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {


  posts = Provider.of<List<Post>>(context);
```

I want just the new post to appear to the user so I need to check the database for that and because I cant do that in build widget I use futurebuilder widget.

```
 FutureBuilder(
      future: checkView(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done )
```

checkView function

```
Future<List<Post>> checkView() async {
if (user != null) voter = await databaseService.getVoterData();


  for (int i = 0; i < posts.length; i += 1) {
    if (!await databaseService.checkViewed(posts[i].postId)) {
      newPosts.add(posts[i]);
    }
  }

}

if (newPosts != null) 
  if (newPosts.length > 0) 
    return newPosts;

return null;

}
```

the problem is checkView is get called multiple time also  newPosts.add(posts[i]) executed multiple times and I cant put it in initState() because I need to get the data from the provider first.

i'm really frustrated because there is no proper documentation of how things work in futuerbuilder and why it called multiple times.

can anyone provide me with the best way to implement this. Please.

Comment: Because you are providing a list in return, here you are returning newPosts. So thats why it called multiple times

Comment: No, sorry you are wrong I tried to return one post but same problem